# How to add Year list using for loop in datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datatable

I have follwing code but it get error-Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

```
    DataTable dtYear = new DataTable();
    int Year1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")); 
    for (i = 1980; i <= Year1; i++)   
    {
       dtYear.Rows.Add(i); 
    } 
     ddlYear.DataSource = dtYear; 
     ddlYear.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is this _even_ compile? I don't think there is `<=>` operator in C#.

Comment: is `i <=> Year1` in your loop a typo?

Comment: yes I believe first mistake is that only remove one thing out of that, i dont knw what your trying out of it, if it cant go less cant go up cant ne equal what will it do

Comment: you are not adding any coluns in your datatable...

Comment: home dtYear.Columns.Add( "Year", typeof(string));

Comment: Type should be int dtYear.Columns.Add( "Year", typeof(int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "Year" column to the DataTable first.

```
dtTable.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
```

You can use the `Year` property of the `DateTime`.

```
int Year1 = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

And also you should use a valid compare operator in the for condition. `<=>` is not valid in c#.

```
for (i = 1980; i <= Year1; i++)   
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your DataTable doesn't contain any columns - so you cant add a row containing a value for a column.

### Edit:

Change your code like this:

```
DataTable dtYear = new DataTable();

dtYear.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));   // add this line

int Year1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")); 
for (i = 1980; i <=> Year1; i++)   
{
   dtYear.Rows.Add(i); 
} 
 ddlYear.DataSource = dtYear; 
 ddlYear.DataBind();
```

Comment: I wrote same in comments,saw this after completing.

Comment: I would use `typeof(int)` instead, since years are numbers, not text strings. Also, ints are what is being added to the rows anyway.

Comment: @kai Your right, this was just a shot from the hip. ;-) I corrected my code.

Comment: `int Year1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")); `equals `int Year1 = DateTime.Now.Year;` there is no convertion required

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code will even compile, so how is it throwing an error.

use Data Columns before assigning values to row.

here is some modification in your code.

```
            DataTable dtYear = new DataTable(); 
            int Year1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
            //add columns to DataTable
            dtYear.Columns.Add("Years",typeof(int), null);

            for (int i = 1980; i <= Year1; i++) 
            {
                dtYear.Rows.Add(i);
            } 


           ddlYear.DataSource = dtYear;
           ddlYear.DataTextField = "Years";
           ddlYear.DataBind();
```

hope this will help.

Comment: @Pravin also add `ddlYear.DataTextField = "Years";` after DataSource

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the column to the DataTable first:

```
 DataTable dtYear = new DataTable();
 dtYear.Columns.Add("year",typeof(int)); // add the column
 int Year1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
 for (int i = 1980; i <= Year1; i++)
 {
     dtYear.Rows.Add(i);
 }
 ddlYear.DataSource = dtYear;
 ddlYear.DataBind();
```